# How i Update or Change Paswword in Asp.net Core 2.0

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I want Password update in My application.
this is my Login IAction

**Controller**

```
    [HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(string returnUrl = null)
    {
        // Clear the existing external cookie to ensure a clean login process
        await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme);

        ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
        return View();
    }
[HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl = null)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);

            if (result.Succeeded)
            {

                _logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }
            if (result.RequiresTwoFactor)
            {
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(LoginWith2fa), new { returnUrl, model.RememberMe });
            }
            if (result.IsLockedOut)
            {
                _logger.LogWarning("User account locked out.");
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Lockout));
            }

            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
                return View(model);
            }
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

Now My current Email and Password is

Email : **john@gmail.com**

Password : **john@gmail.com123**

and i want Update Password **john@gmail.com123** to **john@gmail.com677**

Comment: ASP.Net Identity has a UserManager.

Comment: can you please Tell how i update current password ?

Answer (score 0):

If you use asp.net core 2.0 Identity from template(Individual User Account), you would be able to update your password in `ChangePassword` view, url is `https://localhost:xxxx/Manage/ChangePassword`.

Use `await _userManager.ChangePasswordAsync(user, model.OldPassword, model.NewPassword);`to update passwword.

You would see how to achieve that completely in `ManageController.cs`.

```
[HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ChangePassword()
    {
        var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
        if (user == null)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException($"Unable to load user with ID '{_userManager.GetUserId(User)}'.");
        }

        var hasPassword = await _userManager.HasPasswordAsync(user);
        if (!hasPassword)
        {
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(SetPassword));
        }

        var model = new ChangePasswordViewModel { StatusMessage = StatusMessage };
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ChangePassword(ChangePasswordViewModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }

        var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
        if (user == null)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException($"Unable to load user with ID '{_userManager.GetUserId(User)}'.");
        }

        var changePasswordResult = await _userManager.ChangePasswordAsync(user, model.OldPassword, model.NewPassword);
        if (!changePasswordResult.Succeeded)
        {
            AddErrors(changePasswordResult);
            return View(model);
        }

        await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
        _logger.LogInformation("User changed their password successfully.");
        StatusMessage = "Your password has been changed.";

        return RedirectToAction(nameof(ChangePassword));
    }
```